# Отсутствие запятой в предложении "У меня получилось что-то(?) похожее на торт"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

> У меня получилось что-то(?) похожее на торт.

Как можно объяснить отсутствие запятой в данном предложении?

Comment: На вопросы типа "почему нет?" настолько трудно отвечать, что я объявил бы их "вне закона". Давайте поставим вопрос по-другому: почему у вас возникли сомнения? На каком основании можно предположить  наличие запятой?

Comment: Правило есть! ))) С наступающим!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лиза Запорожец, я долго уговаривал себя дать на ваш вопрос ответ, отличающийся от двух имеющихся, в конце концов уговорил.
Сначала - собственно ответ.

> Как можно объяснить отсутствие запятой в данном предложении?

*Объяснить можно тем и только тем, что запятая в принципе возможна, но придаст фразе несколько необычный смысл, вернее всего - нежелательный для автора*.

Я отнюдь не хочу сказать, что изложенные и процитированные моими предшественницами вещи неправильны по сути, но уже по тому, как вы ставите вопрос, сомнительно, что вам сразу зайдут в душу формулировки Розенталя. Я попробую предельно упростить.

Оба варианта - с запятой и без - в принципе возможны. Чтобы в этом убедиться, рассмотрим более очевидную фразу.

***Я увидела собаку(,) похожую на кошку.***

Как поступит автор, задумавшись над этой запятой, если поймет, что эти варианты слегка отличны друг от друга? 
Вариант с запятой означает примерно следующее. *Я увидела собаку, которая была похожа на кошку.* Здесь декларируется прежде всего то, что увиденное было собакой, а похожесть на кошку просто уточняет основной смысл. Если же написать эту фразу без запятой, то её смысл сведется к тому, что *увидела похожую на кошку собаку*. Тут собака и похожесть на кошку одинаково важны, кабы кошка не важнее. Всё это и называется мудреным словосочетанием "смысловое единство".

Если разницу между вариантами вы(или автор) не видите, то смело пишите без запятой уже потому, что так проще. А если видите, то задумайтесь, какому из разобранных вариантов больше подходит случай, когда вместо собаки стоит "что-то" - то есть неопределенное местоимение. Вряд ли у автора неопределенное "что-то" будет центром высказывания, не зря же оно называется неопределенным. Скорее всего тут именно единство всей конструкции "что-то похожее на торт": уберите торт - и фраза не просто потеряет часть смысла, она превратится в полную бессмыслицу. Поэтому запятая, если автор не слишком большой оригинал, и не нужна.

Вот все это и сформулировано у Розенталя (см. ответы Галина Аванесова и Sharon) в спрессованном академическом виде. Но для его понимания требуется некоторая подготовка. Я изложил некую адаптацию.

Comment: Бессодержательные комментарии типа "Браво!" не приветствуются, но я не смог удержаться. Такое объяснение, как хороший крем, легко впитывается кожей и проникает в кровь.

Comment: Пожалуй, этот ответ оказался самым информативным, даже несмотря на его простоту. Спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 5):

> Если **определение предваряет указательное, определительное или
>   притяжательное местоимение, то в этом случае запятая между ними не
>   ставится**, например:
>
> *Всем пишущим диктант следует быть внимательными.*
>
> *Завтра этим присутствующим на занятии не нужно приходить.*

[У Розенталя:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=104)

**3.** Определительный оборот, стоящий после неопределённого местоимения, обычно **не обособляется**, так как образует единое целое с предшествующим местоимением: *Её большие глаза… искали в моих **что-нибудь похожее на надежду*** (Л.); *В нём уснули все желания, кроме желания думать о чём-то невыразимом словами* (М. Г.); *На лице его промелькнуло **нечто похожее на усмешку**.*

Answer (score 5):

**У меня получилось что-то похожее на торт.**

Сравнить: **Наконец у меня всё-таки получилось что-то,  похожее на торт.**

Во втором предложении менее тесная   связь оборота с определяемым словом, но в принципе в обоих случаях **обособление факультативно.**

Пояснение

1) Если  определительный оборот стоит после определяемого слова, то это позиция, характерная для обособления.
Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

Обособляются ...так называемые определительные обороты, стоящие **после существительного или субстантивированного слова.**

2) Но в нашем случае нужно учесть, что определяемое слово выражено **неопределенным местоимением** (см. ответ Galina Avanesova), в этом случае оборот чаще не обособляется.

3) Однако Розенталь указывает, что  **при менее тесной связи слов и при наличии после местоимения паузы оборот обособляется** (выделяется запятыми).

4) Надо сказать, что оборот **не обособляется примерно в девяти случаях из десяти** (по данным Нацкорпуса). **Но как же определить наличие или отсутствие тесной связи?**

5) Рассмотрим пример: На его лице блуждала усмешка, в которой сквозили и жалость, и удивление, **и еще что-то, похожее на злость.** [Людмила Лаврова. Лишние (1999) // «Дружба народов», 1999.07.15]

Здесь местоимение ***что-то*** входит в однородный ряд, и на него падает ударение. Соответственно делается пауза, которая обозначается запятой.